# how can farm pool be claimed automatically every week without to claim it and sign?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to set up a kind of automatic rewards claim without having to sign the orders which would be to be able to do on all the networks and directly interact with the contract of the pool where I have my liquidity. I need help I don't know where to start.

Comment: Can you describe a little more about what's the problem? What will be claimed? How the claim will be done? Who would be able to claim?

Comment: You should be able to create a Safe module for this. E.g. similar to https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules/tree/master/dutchx_seller